# Android Studio Decryption unsuccessful on newest SDKs (Google API)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

i'm trying to run the Android Emulator with new SDKs (Adnroid 7). It was marked with Google API, but when it starts it wants me to enter a password. When i put in something, it shows me "Decryption Unsuccessful". However it doesn't happen with an SDK not marked with "Google API".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you find out a solution? I'm having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: No, same issue and no one has an idea why :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now! You have to move the .android folder to another location and set a new system-variable ANDROID_HOME_SDK with the path to it.

Rerun Android Studio!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you used cyryllic or something other, non Latin characters in your user name. Just [rename your user folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/rename-user-account-folder-in-windows-10-preview/88033eca-6b32-47c5-90ac-a5e7af17d094) and be happy.

Comment: indeed i got non-ascii characters in my name, but i created a linked folder in c:/ so i can bypass the issue